# Prove basis exists for a weird transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose that $S : \Bbb{R}^2 → \Bbb{R}^2$ is a linear transformation such that $S^2 = S, S\ne 0 $ and $ S \ne I$ Prove that there is a basis for $\Bbb{R}^2$ with respect to which the matrix $A_S$ of $S$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 \\   
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I kind of understand what the linear map does by multiplying a few vectors with the given matrix. However, I have no idea how to prove that a basis for $\Bbb{R}^2$ with respect to which the matrix $A_S$

Comment: Note that $S^2 = S$ implies that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $S$, so pick an eigenvector as the first basis element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to prove that there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that
$$
S = P
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 \\   
\end{pmatrix}
P^{-1}
$$
i.e. that $S$ is diagnonalizable, with eigenvalues $0,1$.

Now, suppose $v$ is an eigenvector, with eigenvalue $\lambda$, so $S v = \lambda v$. Then
$$
Sv = S(Sv) = \lambda Sv = \lambda^2 v
$$
therefore $\lambda = \lambda^2$ in $\Bbb{R}$, but the only two idempotents in $\Bbb{R}$ are $0$ and $1$. Since $S \neq 0$ they cannot be both $0$ and, if they were both $1$ then its [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) would be
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 \\   
\end{pmatrix}
$$
since $S \neq I$ by hypothesis. But this isn't possible because
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 \\   
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 \\   
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 \\
  0 & 1 \\   
\end{pmatrix}
\neq
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 \\   
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Therefore we conclude that indeed that $S$ must have both eigenvalues $0,1$, as required.